# CSS multi-level dropdown menu positioning

Tags: css, menu, drop-down-menu, positioning

I am developing a website [linked here](http://www.janwillemtroost.nl/dev) with 3-level dropdown menus (main, and 2 sublevels). I'm developing with MODx cms and Wayfinder for menu-creation.
The CSS is picked somewhere, higly modified and works, but I do not understand 1 detail.

When you look to the site's menu: rightmost main-menu item ("**links**") --> **Links 1.2** , the 2nd level submenu of "**Links 1.2**" nicely pops up to the left of the 1st level submenu (inside the lighter contentbody.

The 2nd level submenus are positioned by a "**Left: 120px** (1 item width): which offsets it and shifts it to the right. See e.g. "beeld & geluid" --> "Audio" --> 2nd level submenu

For this rightmost submenu popping up inside the content it works by **shifting it to the left** by using a negative offset: **Left: -240px;** (which is the width of **2** items)

What I miss is: why this negative offset has to be 240px 2 items in stead of 1 item of 120px. The last is what I expected.

The CSS contains comments and the involved lines are 155 -161 in the css-file (you have to get it from the site since as a new user I'm unable to add a 2nd link because new users are limited to 1 link at max)

Question:

Can anyone explain this to me? The negative offset of 2 in stead of 1 item?

Best regards,

Hans Troost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that in the first dropdown menu, the list-items are set relatively. Then the second ul goes in there, but is positioned absolutely and adjecent to the items (to the right in all cases). However, because the sub-submenu beneath the item "links" would fall of the website, it is positioned left -240px. Not -120px, because it would sit on top the of the first submenu. Does that make sense?

```
--------------------------------------
Top item 1 | top item 2 | top item 3 |
--------------------------------------
                        | sub item 1 |
           ---------------------------* * * * * * *
           | subsubitem | sub item 2 | subsubmenu * <--  this is the ul that is positioned
           ---------------------------* * * * * * *      absolute
           -240px       -120px        0px          120px
```

**conclusion**

So my point is that the ul is positioned in the same place, however the li's are moved to the left. And therefore it needs -240px because it positioned relative to the ul.

Comment: Thank a lot: exactly the kind of answer I was hoping for. Good explanation: I get it now.